# Using space as delimiter

Tags: java, string

I am trying to delimit the `,` and space my input is `21, May, 2012` my output should be `2012-May-21`.

```
String s = args[0];
String[] s1 = s.split(",\\s+");
System.out.print(s1[2] + "-" + s1[1] + "-" + s1[0]);
```

It is working if I am writing for only `,` delimiter but getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when trying for space as delimiter.

Comment: It's not clear how many spaces and commas may be delimiters. Can be comma without space regarded as delimiter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since both `,`,space are optional as mentioned in the comment..

```
String[] s1 = s.split(",|\\s+");
```

---

Though I won't use regex to parse date

```
 input=input.replaceAll("\\s*","");//remove any space if any
 java.util.Date date= (new SimpleDateFormat("dd,MMM,yyyy")).parse(input);
 String output=(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd")).format(date);
```

Comment: @Kite Player, That's because the "21, May, 2012" is not as per the format described by the SimpleDateFormat pattern "yyyy-MM-dd".

Comment: @KitePlayer we need to remove all space from input string..check out the edit

Comment: Works fine as expected. Already gave `+1` . If , possible I ll give `+10` for your great explanation and answer.

Comment: Tq for the info... still getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at SOP line Anirudh...

Comment: I am looking for solution using split which is not working. -@KitePlayer

Comment: @jayadeep i guess the input would be in a wrong format..this may happen if there are less than 2 `,` delimiters or no `,` delimiters at all..check your input

Comment: Write a program which accepts the date (date month year), separated by coma/space or both and print the date format of YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: @jayadeep ok..so the delimiters may be `space` or `,` or both..check out my edited ans

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using [String#replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) :

```
 s.replaceAll(",\\s*", "-");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    String date = " 21 , May, 2012";
    String[] s1 = date.split(",\\s*");
    System.out.println(s1[2].trim() + "-" + s1[1].trim() + "-" + s1[0].trim());
```